# after click Search - chosen values are reset, not stored

Tags: c#, asp.net

I do not understand how implement logic for saving chosen parameters after click 'Search'

there is aspx file:

```
<form class="search_css" runat="server">
    <div class="search_div_search_box">
         <table class="filter_component_css">
              <tr>
                  <td>miap</td>
                  <td><asp:TextBox CssClass="search_format" ID="miap_textbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                   <td>purchase order</td>
                   <td><asp:TextBox CssClass="search_format" ID="po_textbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                   <td>material desc</td>
                   <td><asp:TextBox CssClass="search_format" ID="material_desc_textbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                   <td>supplier</td>
                   <td><asp:TextBox CssClass="search_format" ID="supplier_textbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                   <td>manufacturer</td>
                   <td><asp:TextBox CssClass="search_format" ID="manufacturer_textbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                   <td>spare parts</td>
                   <td><asp:CheckBox CssClass="search_format" ID="parts_checkbox" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="spareParts_Checked" ViewStateMode="Enabled"/></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                   <td>first fills</td>
                   <td><asp:CheckBox CssClass="search_format" ID="fills_checkbox" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="firstFills_Checked" ViewStateMode="Enabled"/></td>
              </tr>
              <tr><td>special tools</td>              
                  <td><asp:Checkbox CssClass="search_format" ID="tools_checkbox" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="specialTools_Checked" ViewStateMode="Enabled"/>
                  </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td colspan="2">
                      <asp:Button ID="buttonReset"  CssClass="filter_component_css_3" runat="server" Text="Reset" OnClick="submitResetClick"/>
                      <asp:Button ID="buttonSearch"  CssClass="filter_component_css_3" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="submitSearchClick"/>
                  </td>
              </tr>
         </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

c# class:

```
<script runat="server">
    //spare parts variable 
    int sp_id=0; 

    //first fills variable 
    int ff_id=0;

    //special tools variable 
    int st_id=0;


    void spareParts_Checked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (parts_checkbox.Checked)
        {
            sp_id = 1;
        }
    }

    void firstFills_Checked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (fills_checkbox.Checked)
        {
            ff_id = 1;
        }
    }

    void specialTools_Checked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         if (tools_checkbox.Checked)
         {
             st_id = 1;
         }
    }


    protected void submitSearchClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         ViewState.Add("flag", true);
         ViewState.Add("sp_id", sp_id);
         ViewState.Add("ff_id", ff_id);
         ViewState.Add("st_id", st_id);

         GridViewS.DataSource = SqlDataSource_Search;

         Response.Write("miap like '%" + miap_textbox.Text + "%' and pocode like '%" + po_textbox.Text + "%' and materialdescription like '%" + material_desc_textbox.Text + "%' and suppliername like '%" + supplier_textbox.Text + "%' and manufacturername like '%" + manufacturer_textbox.Text
                                + "%' and spareparts =" + sp_id + " and firstfills=" + ff_id + " and specialtools =" + st_id + "");


         SqlDataSource_Search.FilterExpression = "miap like '%" + miap_textbox.Text + "%' and pocode like '%" + po_textbox.Text + "%' and materialdescription like '%" + material_desc_textbox.Text + "%' and suppliername like '%" + supplier_textbox.Text + "%' and manufacturername like '%" + manufacturer_textbox.Text
                                + "%' and spareparts =" +sp_id+ " and firstfills=" +ff_id+ " and specialtools =" + st_id + "";

         GridViewS.DataBind();

    }
</script>
```

e.g.
if I check 3 check-boxes -  spare parts, first fills, special tools - click 'Search' >
response write result:
... and spareparts =1 and firstfills=1 and specialtools =1

if after that I uncheck first fills only - click 'Search' >
... and spareparts =0 and firstfills=0 and specialtools =0

**Result which I need:**
... and spareparts =1 and firstfills=0 and specialtools =1

Comment: You have to enable `AutoPostBack` on the CheckBoxes, else the Checked methods won't fire and the variables won't be set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CheckBoxList instead and tweak this for your requiement :

**aspx**

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chklBidType" runat="server">
 <asp:ListItem Text="spare parts" Value="1" />
 <asp:ListItem Text="first fills" Value="2" />
 <asp:ListItem Text="special tools" Value="3" />
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

**cs**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
 string strBidType = "";
 foreach(ListItem cBox in chklBidType.Items) 
 {
   if(cBox.Selected) 
   {
    strBidType += cBox.Value + " / ";
   }
 }
 Response.Write(strBidType);
}
```